# Проблема с авторизацией smbclient

Tags: python, smb

Пытаюсь закинуть файлы на удалённый сервер через SMB а т.е через smbclient но не проходит коннект, на тестовом сервере все работало стабильно на нём был настроен доступ к smb через пароль а на боевом сервере smb без пароля(по требованиям поставить пароль на дынный smb сервер нельзя), пожалуйста подскажите как решить данную проблему и заходить на smb сервер без пароля.

```
import smbclient  


pass_user = 'user' 
server = '10.0.0.1'  

smbclient.register_session(server, username=pass_user, password=pass_user)


raise SMBException("SMB encryption or signing was required but session was authenticated as a guest "
smbprotocol.exceptions.SMBException: SMB encryption or signing was required but session was authenticated as a guest which does not support encryption or signing
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smbclient/_pool.py:412: UserWarning: Failed to close connection 10.0.0.1:445: Received unexpected status from the server: The remote user session has been deleted. (3221225987) STATUS_USER_SESSION_DELETED: 0xc0000203
  warnings.warn("Failed to close connection %s: %s" % (name, str(e)))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Volkodaff
`import smbclient

pass_user = 'user'
server = '10.0.0.1'

smbclient.register_session(server, username=pass_user, password=pass_user)`

конечный smb сервер без пароля